# code output default value instead of user input value

Tags: java, object

```
package homework4;

public class CreditCardNumber {
private String issuerID = "000000";
private String accountNum = "999999999";
private int checkDigit = 0;

public CreditCardNumber(String TempissuerID, String TempaccountNum)
{
    if(TempissuerID != null && TempaccountNum != null && TempissuerID.length() == 6 && TempaccountNum.length() == 9)
        if(Digits(TempissuerID) && Digits(TempaccountNum))
        {
            issuerID = TempissuerID;
            accountNum = TempaccountNum;
            calcCheckDigits();
        }

}

public boolean Digits(String temp1)
{
    String temp = "0123456789";
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < temp1.length();i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < temp.length();j++)
            if(temp1.charAt(i) != temp.charAt(j))
            {
                count++;

            }
    if(count == temp1.length()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public CreditCardNumber(){}

public String getID()
{
    return issuerID;
}

public String getAccNum()
{
    return accountNum;
}

public int getDigits()
{
    return checkDigit;
}

private void calcCheckDigits()
{
    int sum;
    sum = checkSum();
    if((sum + checkDigit) % 10 != 0)    
    {
        checkDigit = sum - (sum % 10);
    }

}

public void CreateCred(String TempissuerID)
{
    if(TempissuerID != null && TempissuerID.length() ==6 && Digits(TempissuerID))
    {
        issuerID = TempissuerID;
    }
    else 
    {
        issuerID = "000000";
    }
    StringBuilder TempString = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++)
    {
        TempString = TempString.append((Math.random()*(9-0+1)+0));
        System.out.printf("%d",TempString);
    }
    accountNum = TempString.toString();
    calcCheckDigits();
}

 private int checkSum()
 {       StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
         int num;
         int sum =0;
         for(int i = 0 ; i <issuerID.length();i++)
         {
                 temp.append(issuerID.length());
                 for(int j = 0 ; j < accountNum.length(); j++)

                 temp.append(accountNum.length());
         }
         for(int k = 0 ; k < temp.length(); k +=2)
         {
                 num = temp.charAt(k) - '0';
                 num *=2;
                 if(num > 9)
                   num = 1 + (num % 10);
                 temp.setCharAt(k, (char) num);
         }
         for(int v = 0 ; v < temp.length(); v++)
         {
                 sum += temp.charAt(v) - '0';
         }

         return sum;
 }

 public String toString()
 {      
     return issuerID + accountNum + checkDigit;

 }
}
```

// in another file

```
package homework4;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog4 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{   CreditCardNumber[] cred1;
    CreditCardNumber cred2 = getInput();
    Display(cred2);
    cred1 = getInputArray();
}

public static CreditCardNumber getInput() {
    String ID;
    String accNum;
    CreditCardNumber tempCred;      
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Please enter issuer ID:");
    ID = scanner.next();
    System.out.printf("Please enter account number:");
    accNum = scanner.next();
    tempCred = new CreditCardNumber(ID, accNum);
    return tempCred;
}
public static void Display(CreditCardNumber cred2)
{

    System.out.printf("The complete number from your input:");
    System.out.println(cred2);
    return;

}

public static CreditCardNumber[] getInputArray()
{
    CreditCardNumber[] tempArray;
    String tempID;
    int size;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Please enter size of the aray:");
    size = scanner.nextInt();
    if(size < 1)
    {
        size = 1;
    }
    tempArray = new CreditCardNumber[size];
    System.out.printf("Please enter issuer ID:");
    tempID = scanner.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

    }

    return tempArray;
}

}
```

hi i have a question on the getInput method in main, when i compile the code and run it the out put is

```
enter issuer ID:321321
Please enter account number:654654654
The complete number from your input:0000009999999990
```

which is the default value for issuerId and acountNum from the CreditCardNumber class

but what i want is this output

```
Enter a credit card issuer number: 321321
Enter an account number: 654654654
The complete number from your input: 
3213 2165 4654 6549
```

with 4 space between each 4 character 
why does my code output the default value instead of the user input value ?

can anyone show me whats wrong with the code or getinput() function?

thank in advance

Comment: Why is there a 9 at the end of `3213 2165 4654 6549`?

Comment: i have no idea that was the test run i got from my prof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just debugged your code, your digit method is returning false for this particular input , which will fail the if condition  in the constructor, thus it would still hold the default values.

just use regex to check if the string passed is numeric.

change your Digits method like below.

```
    public boolean Digits(String temp1)
    {
        if(temp1.matches("[0-9]+")){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

change yout toString method like this:

```
 public String toString()
 {   String s="";   
     String str= issuerID + accountNum ;

     return str;

 }
```

it gave me the output:

```
Please enter issuer ID:321321
Please enter account number:654654654
The complete number from your input:321321654654654
```

Comment: well i change the code now i got The complete number from your input:321321654654654-930

Comment: @user1787811 kewl, so is it working now ?? is that the desired output ?? and if this is an assignment, i wouldnt recommend you to use regex.

Comment: @user1787811 but i strongly recommend not to use regex if this is an assignment.

Comment: how do i add checkdigits number in lke this 3213216546546549 so i want to add that number 9 in

Comment: to get the first digit of checkdigits, you will have to format it, but first, y do you want such output??

Comment: oh that what my professor want but it doesn't make sense though

Answer (score 0):

`if(temp1.charAt(i) != temp.charAt(j))` should be `if(temp1.charAt(i) == temp.charAt(j))` in `public boolean Digits(String)`.

You're whitelisting the characters, so you should be counting characters that *do* match, not the ones that don't.

Another way to verify that a string is made of at least one digit:

```
public boolean Digits(String str) {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if(str.charAt(i) < '0' || str.charAt(i) > '9')
            return false;
    return str.length() > 0;
}
```

Haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: well i did it the other way, the if statement would have looked different if i did it your way.Well, I tested my Digits method and it work as well

Comment: @user1787811 My first point should still hold, though. Did you try that out?